# I am getting an error when I am trying to setup chaquopy(The error reads: failed to start (org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException)

Tags: android, chaquopy

[This is the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qz9wj.png)

I am getting this error when I am trying to setup chaquopy, using macOS and python 3.6.

I am on the Requirements step on [setting up chaquopy](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython). I have added the plugin, did ABI selection, development, requirements.

The error encountered is:

`failed to start (org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/usr/local/lib/python3.6'') Please set python.buildPython to your Python executable path.`

My `build.gradle` is below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vishrutjaipuria.facialrecognition"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
        python {
            buildPython "/usr/local/lib/python3.6"
        }
        python {
            pip {
                install "scipy==1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
android {
    flavorDimensions "abi"
    productFlavors {
        arm {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a" }
        }
        x86 {
            dimension "abi"
            ndk { abiFilters "x86" }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [the documentation](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#development) says, `buildPython` should be set to the Python executable, not the Python library directory. Set it to the executable path: this is probably /usr/local/**bin**/python3.6, but check for yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar error (`A problem occurred starting process 'command '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/os.py''. Please set buildPython to your Python executable path.` ) while trying (by the statement starting with `buildPython`) to set the location of the Python executable file in Android Studio installed in a Macbook.

**Way to solve the problem**

One of the ways to solve the problem can be by setting the exact location of the Python executable file. But I do not see any necessity to set the location manually since Chaquopy will try to find Python on the PATH with the standard command for the OS as mentioned [here](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html#buildpython). Therefore, just removing the statement (`buildPython "/usr/local/lib/python3.6"` *something like that presenting a location*) solved my problem since I installed Python on Mac earlier and Chaquopy got (as far as I understood) the location of the exe file through standard command.